# Spring-boot > implicitly auto register a 3rd party bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This may be an impossible task, but here goes...

#### Is it possible to register a spring bean, by (ONLY) adding a jar to the classpath of a `spring-boot` application?

**Scenario:** I would like to create a non-intrusive `plugin` jar, which when imported into a `spring-boot` project's classpath, will automatically be picked up and provide a service (e.g. via a `RestController`).

#### Constraints

- I don't want to change or reconfigure the existing `spring-boot` application (i.e. no additional scan paths or bean config).
- I don't have any knowledge of the target `spring-boot` application's package structure/scan paths.

I guess I was hoping that by default **Spring** scan's its own package structure (i.e. `org.springframework.**` looking for the presence of database libs, etc) and I could piggy-back off that - I haven't had any luck (so far).

I've setup an [example project in github](https://github.com/nickgrealy/spring-plugin-poc), to further clarify/illustrate my example and attempts.

#### ** Solution Addendum **

This bit that got it working, was to add the following file, which points to an `@Configuration` config file...

**[plugin-poc\src\main\resources\META-INF\spring.factories](https://github.com/nickgrealy/spring-plugin-poc/blob/master/plugin-poc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories)**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=org.thirdpartyplugin.PluginConfiguration
```

Comment: Hopefully, we do not scan `org.springframework.*` (that would be crazy). You're asking for something that is straightforward with boot really. As Mathias wrote already, an auto-config of yours in that jar would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in such cases you would try to add a spring auto configuration that is annotated with [`@ConditionalOnClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) to be only evaluated if the given class is on the classpath. This class can register the bean and would just be evaluated if the conditional evaluates to true

Here is the relevant part of the spring boot documentation : [Creating your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration)

Comment: The link to the auto-configuration and info on the `spring.factories` file was all that I required. (No need for `@Conditional...`). Thanks again!